# Are there any Italian craft beers?

Tags: craft-beers

I'm spending my summer in Florence, Italy. I've been here for a week already and I've since realized they much rather prefer wine, but I don't. I'm looking for some Italian craft beers because I don't know how much longer I can drink Heineken. So any ideas?

Comment: Why not an _outstanding_ one? ;) https://www.whitedogbeer.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the highest ranked breweries in Italy include:

- Le Baladin (Highly recommended but these might be harder to find)
- Panil Birra Artigianale
- Revelation Cat Craft Brewing
- Birra del Borgo
- Birrificio Toccalmatto
- Birrificio Lambrate
- Maltus Faber

Note that in Europe there aren't as many mega breweries so local craft brewing is much more popular.  You should look for a local brewery for fresher and more easily accessible (in terms of cost and rarity).

Comment: Where to drink Baladin in Rome: https://goo.gl/maps/mNWDtLmH6E4XKQVs8 but other similar pubs may be in other locations.

Answer (score 4):

The question could be changed to "craft Italian beer" or "Italian real ale" instead of good. That would fix the question quality. 
To answer the better question, there are about 360 micro-breweries in italy under the umbrella MoBI organization (http://www.movimentobirra.it/) which is similar to CAMRA and has an English translation to their website. I would recommend using that as an initial source of information as breweries change and I am not familiar with the Florence area. 
http://www.pintamedicea.com/birra/ based in Florence may also be helpful depending on your level of Italian language skills.